# Using lookupedit on XtraGrid columns

Tags: c#, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

I have a xtraGrid with 6 columns. I want to make one columns to lookupEdit columns.
how can i insert my datasource(datatable or dataset) on lookupeditcolumns.
thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

what did you try so far? Usually I use the designer and create the RepositoryItem so it exists in the code. then in my Page Load or Page Init I simply assign the datasource to that RepositoryItem. It's easy :)

Comment: **Hi, 
here look my code and design.**

**First i create a lookupedit column on my grid.**

Look --> http://i54.tinypic.com/330a7fd.jpg


**and second i put mydatasource on my grid's source**



**when i was run the program i cant edit or select lookupedit column.**

Look --> http://i53.tinypic.com/108g5k8.jpg